# How expo builds the key required by Google

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to add Google Signing, but I open my Expo project in android studio, and there is no Build> Generate Signed Bundle/APK. Should I create a native android application, open it and Generate Signed Bundle/APK

[image]

AKTest is my new native Android project. The following is me in android studio. Is this correct?
[image]

google signature needs to provide a key, how can I get it
[image]

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#sign_release

Comment: Yes ,create your own key in android studio helps you during updates

Comment: thank you for your reply. I want to confirm whether the key store path is the jrs file generated by expo fetch:android:keystore. I don't understand whether I should create a new jrs or use expo provided

Comment: Why dont you allow expo to do all the work? You can always download the keystore file so why doing a lot of effort.

Comment: Because I want to add a Google signature so that I can use the app bundle format package, Google needs me to upload the key before joining, how should I get it?

Comment: I have been using the apk format before, and I used to manage the key with expo before, because Google’s new regulations require aab format, how should I deal with it

Comment: dear, you need a *.pepk file (privat key) which is required to be uploaded in above screenshots.  Please read this link carefully. https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#enroll_existing